# Travis-CI not building my configuration

Tags: android, gradle, travis-ci

I have an Android project which I am trying to build on Travis-CI.  The project consists of an app module and a library module.  Travis-CI always errors out with this:

> Configuration with name 'release' not found.

This doesn't make sense, since gradle is building my project fine on my local machine.  So how to understand this cryptic Travis error?

Thanks,
Igor

EDIT:
The full script is here -

```
sudo: false
language: android
cache: apt

addons:
  apt:
    packages:
      - s3cmd

android:
  components:
    - build-tools-22.0.1
    - android-22

    # Emulator components
    - sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-22

  licenses:
    - 'android-sdk-preview-license-52d11cd2'
    - 'android-sdk-license-.+'
    - 'android-googletv-license-99eda7fb'

jdk:
  - oraclejdk8

before_install:
  - chmod +x ./DrNow/gradlew

# Emulator Management: Create, Start and Wait
before_script:
  - echo no | android create avd --force -n test -t android-19 --abi armeabi-v7a
  - emulator -avd test -no-skin -no-audio -no-window &
  - android-wait-for-emulator
  - adb shell input keyevent 82 &

# Invoke test scripts here
script:
  - cd DrNow
  - ./gradlew test

cache:
  directories:
    - $HOME/.gradle
```

The full error in Travis-CI console looks like this:

> The command "cd DrNow" exited with 0.
>   27.38s$ ./gradlew test
>   Loading > Resolving dependencies 'classpath'Configuring > 0/5 projects > root project > Resolving dependencies ':classpat1/5 projects > :app > Compiling script into cache > Resolving dependencies ':app:classpath' > Compiling script into cachee/travis/build/chaione/healthhousecalls-android/DrNow/app/build.gradle
>   Configuring > 1/5 projects > :app> Configuring > 1/5 projects > :app2/5 projects > :libraries:contexthub-android-sdk:contexthub-and3/5 projects> Configuring > 3/5 projectsFAILURE: 
>   Configuring > 3/5 projectsBuild failed with an exception.
>   Configuring > 3/5 projects> Configuring > 3/5 projects> Configuring > 3/5 projects> Configuring > 3/5 projects occurred configuring project ':app'.
>   Configuring > 3/5 projects> 
>   Configuring > 3/5 projectsodule contexthub-android-sdk : Configuration with name 'release' not found.
>   Configuring > 3/5 projects> Configuring > 3/5 projects> Configuring > 3/5 projects> Configuring > 3/5 projects--stacktrace
>   Configuring > 3/5 projects> Configuring > 3/5 projects--info
>   Configuring > 3/5 projects> Configuring > 3/5 projects--debug
>   Configuring > 3/5 projectsore log output.
>   Configuring > 3/5 projects> Configuring > 3/5 projectsBUILD FAILED
>   Configuring > 3/5 projects> Configuring > 3/5 projects> Configuring > 3/5 projectse: 23.589 secs
>   Configuring > 3/5 projects
>   The command "./gradlew test" exited with 1.
>   cache.2
>   ...
>   changes detected, packing new archive
>   .
>   .
>   uploading archive
>   Done. Your build exited with 1.

Comment: please show the file

Comment: There might be missing environment variables and gradle might not be able to find something to work correctly. You could try to create a script that works independently of the terminal or command launching it.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix As I mentioned, gradlew builds without a hitch on my local machine.  So what environment variables are you talking about on Travis?

Comment: Here is located this project: contexthub-android-sdk? It is the release configuration of this project that is failing.

Comment: @SandroMachado It is a library project included in my app.  I am compiling it like this: `releaseCompile project(path: ':libraries:contexthub-android-sdk:contexthub-android-sdk', configuration: 'release')
    demoCompile project(path: ':libraries:contexthub-android-sdk:contexthub-android-sdk', configuration: 'release')
    debugCompile project(path: ':libraries:contexthub-android-sdk:contexthub-android-sdk', configuration: 'release')
`

Comment: For some reason that project is not compiling, that looks to be the problem.

Comment: @SandroMachado But it compiles fine on my local machine!!